# How to hide my own page (Qt Installer Framework)

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have a page with serial number checking (`SerialCodePage`). It is implemented and added in installer code after `IntroductionPage`.
This page is needed for Pro version, and for Lite I would like to hide it, without recompile installer code.

I tried to implement it with the help of `installer.removeWizardPage (component, "SerialCodePage");` in componentscript and controlscript, but the function always returns false.
How do I hide this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `removeWizardPage` works only for pages added in QJS.
In my case, I had to add this page to `ScriptEngine::generateQInstallerObject` and use `installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.SerialCode, false);`